# NET8 Blazor calls multiple APIs form a Razor page

Tags: c#, blazor, .net-8.0

I'm creating a website with `Blazor` and `NET8`. In a Razor page, I want to call multiple APIs in order to display data coming from different sources based on the same parameter *Id*.

```
protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
{
    if (firstRender)
        await LoadConjugation();
}

private async Task LoadConjugation()
{
    if (id != 0)
    {
        try
        {
            var respConjugation = await conService.GetConjugationById(id);
            if (respConjugation != null)
            {
                countryCode = respConjugation.Language.GetCountryCode();
                forms = respConjugation.Conjugations;
                language = respConjugation.Language.GetLanguageName();

                ShowError = false;
                StateHasChanged();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ShowError = true;
        }

        if (!ShowError)
        {
            var tasks = new List<Task>();
            tasks.Add(Task.Run(async () => { await UpdateWord(); }));
            tasks.Add(Task.Run(async () => { await UpdateExamples(); }));
            tasks.Add(Task.Run(async () => { await UpdateSynonyms(); }));
            tasks.Add(Task.Run(async () => { await UpdateAntonyms(); }));

            Task t = Task.WhenAll(tasks);
            try
            {
                t.Wait();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Logger?.LogError(ex, "Error loading conjugation");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The *Update* functions just make another call to an API. Although the call in the `LoadConjugation` is successful, the calls for `UpdateWord` and the others have not been called or at least are not executed. What is the correct way or best practice to call multiple APIs on the Blazor page? Is it correct to use `Task`? I like to improve the performance of the page as much as possible.

Comment: You should probably read this [MS Learn article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/httpclient-factory) and implement `HttpClient` instances through the `IHttpClientFactory`.

Comment: I get an SDK with all the calls to the APIs, My issue is to call them in an efficient way, maybe in parallel, to improve the user experience.

Comment: "I get an SDK" .  Does that mean that you're not in control of the `HttpClients` used to make the API calls?  Using the factory gives you multiple client instances that let you run the http requests in parallel.